# should I store passwords in database table using base64 encoding?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, passwords, base64

I am using PBKDF2 encryption to hash password with salt.
should I store hashed password and salt in database after applying base64 encoding?

If I do use the encoding, then the password length becomes 88 from 64, which requires more storage than when I am not using it.

What are advantages and disadvantages for using the encoding?

should I apply it to salts too?

Comment: If base64 encoding is easier for you to work with, just use it. Those 24 extra bytes don't hurt you, since it is unlikely you will query large amounts of passwords from the database at the same time. From a security perspective, there is obviously no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the security side, there is no difference between storing pure bytes, and storing a Base64-encoding of them.

If you store pure bytes, make sure you select the right datatype (e.g. a binary one, not a character one) for your column. If you store base64, you can use a character column with US-ASCII encoding.

Base64 has the advantage that a human can more easily look at the data and see if it is the same as some other, but this is about it - you could easily do the encoding after querying the data, too.